# Android Custom shaped Button

Tags: android, xml, button

I want to create a custom shaped button like below in android with xml(I know I can do it with the image but it isn't one of my options),how to do this?
I started with the rectangle shape and then tried to play with the corners in negative way to make the right side raise but I was unsuccessful.
[image]

Comment: You only want to use xml? Fine, then subclass the `Button` view, add “raised edge” properties and implement custom drawing and touch listeners. That's the complicated, bad to do it. Or you can whine about a better answer that suggests using a drawable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a 9-patch (resizable drawable) as your button background, [read this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html).

Comment: @A.R.H To what reason must it be an xml. This solution seems ok to me